# Nodejs out of memory express

Tags: node.js, express

Hi from time to time my nodejs express on my k8s is crashing

Attached the error

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[25:0x443be70] 16125806 ms: Scavenge 1820.8 (2064.8) -> 1817.3 (2071.0) MB, 20.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.136, current mu = 0.057) allocation failure
[25:0x443be70] 16126455 ms: Mark-sweep 1826.6 (2071.0) -> 1823.3 (2069.0) MB, 611.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.135, current mu = 0.135) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1266842c08a1 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: stringify(this=0x1266842df199 <Object map = 0x3b0313505341>,0x381ecf3c04a9 <undefined>,0x381ecf3c04a9 <undefined>,0x0e04f5b827b1 <Object map = 0xe62d7e5c1d1>,0x1266842df199 <Object map = 0x3b0313505341>)

    1: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3
    2: stringify(aka stringify) [0x163338e6d3d1] [/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1123] [bytecode=0x31af60d3ccc...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x9da7c0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x9db976 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb39f1e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb3a299 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xce5635  [node]
 6: 0xce5cc6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xcf1b5a v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xcf2a65 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xcf5478 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xcc3757 v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
11: 0x106fe69 v8::internal::IncrementalStringBuilder::Extend() [node]
12: 0xdd563f v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [node]
13: 0xdd6ed4 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
14: 0xdd90e5 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeJSReceiverSlow(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSReceiver>) [node]
15: 0xdda822 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
16: 0xdd8ce8 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
17: 0xddb266 v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
18: 0xddbc14 v8::internal::JsonStringify(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
19: 0xbeb50b v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
20: 0x13750d9  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! service-xxx@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the service-billybox@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-18T19_25_22_325Z-debug.log
```

There is no that much details.

Seems on the json parsing from the response.

Do you know how to get more details ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several possible causes of errors like this:

1. A slow leak that builds up memory usage over time, eventually causing you to run out of memory on one of your operations that uses more memory than others.
2. An overly large peak memory usage that just exceeds what is available to nodejs.
3. Just not enough working memory available for what your code is occasionally trying to do.

Since this appears to fail on a `JSON.stringify()` call, you should first check out how large that object was and thus how large the stringified version was going to be.  If that is overly large and thus fills up the working memory you have available for your nodejs process, then you will have your answer there.  The stringified object is just too large.  Either break the object up, find a smaller way to get the result you want (returning a subset of the data) or increase the working memory available to nodejs to accommodate this usage.  It may take some instrumentation and debugging to eventually figure out which object was being processed whenever you run out.

For memory leaks, the best thing to do immediately is to start logging the memory use reported by `process.memoryUsage()` every so often in your server and see if it just keeps going up and up without ever leveling off.  The total process usage should go up as your server first goes through it's initial paces and finds a highwater mark of usage.  The `heapUsed` value should not continue to go up over time unless your server has some large cache that you keep building over time.  From this info, you can then identify next steps based on whether you suspect you do have a leak or do have a peak memory usage problem.